# how to bind data very quickly in combo box in windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

Hi I am  developing one app.In my app 2000 cities are there.these cities  are came from webservice.Now I want to bind these cities into combobox very quickly.Actually it takes 5 mins time for binding data.how to bind data very fastly please help me.

Below is my  code:

```
  var busclient = new NewReloadApp.JsonWebClient();

             var Busresp1 = await busclient.DoRequestAsync(Url.weburl + "getCities");
                    string Busresult1 = Busresp1.ReadToEnd();
                    JArray BusjsonArray = JArray.Parse(Busresult1);

                    for (int j = 0; j < BusjsonArray.Count; j++)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.01));
                        JObject jobj = (JObject)BusjsonArray[j];

                        string id = (string)jobj["cityid"];
                        string cityname = (string)jobj["cityname"];



                        city cit = new city();
                        cit.cityname = cityname;

                        Fromcityname1.Items.Add(cityname);
                        Tocityname1.Items.Add(cityname);
                        Db_Helper.Insert(new Buscities(id, cityname));
                        UserProfileList.Add(cit);
```

Here Fromcityname1,Tocityname1 are comboboxes.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> Fromcityname = new List<string>();
Fromcityname.Add(cityname);
Fromcityname1.ItemSources = Fromcityname;
```

and in xaml

```
<ComboBox x:name="Fromcityname1" ItemSources="{binding}"/>
```

or

```
Fromcityname.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = Fromcityname});
```